# Android DownloadManager crash

Tags: android, файлы, download

Обычные файлы грузятся.
Но, когда имя файла имеет название, например, "Иванов И.И..jpg" - приложение рушится.
Предполагаю, что это из-за 2 точек в названии файла перед расширением.
Проблема:

Или тут: `DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));`
или тут: `request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "Ivanov I.I..jpg");`
DownloadManager  - стандарт.
Есть варианты решения?

```
String url = "https://myserver.com/Ivanov I.I..jpg";
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
request.setDescription("Ivanov I.I..jpg downloading");
request.setTitle("Some title");
// in order for this if to run, you must use the android 3.2 to compile your app
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
}
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "Ivanov I.I..jpg");

// get download service and enqueue file
DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
manager.enqueue(request);
```

Normal files are loaded.
But when the filename has a name, for example, "Ivanov I.I..jpg" - the application crashes.
I assume that this is due to 2 dots in the file name before the extension.
Are there solutions?

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки и на какую строку она указывает

Comment: Предположим на 2 проблему. Парсить имя файла и пытаться переписать название сохраняемого файла?

Comment: Пока вы не приведете текст ошибки и строки, где она возникла, ничем вам помочь не получится

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была таки тут:

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "Ivanov I.I..jpg");
```

Поменял 2 точки и проблема исчезла

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "Ivanov I.I.jpg");
```